# What does it mean to call a class inside a method as a parameter?

Tags: php, oop

I've sometimes seen developers put the name of a class as a parameter in a method of another class.
 I would like to know what that means, is it something like inheritance? Does this make it possible for the method to make use of methods and fields of that class being passed as a parameter?

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class SimpleClass
{
    public function sayHello(): void
    {
        echo("Hello!");
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static function main(SimpleClass): void
    {
        //sayHello();
    }
}
```

I tested the code above, but reported an error. However, I've seen some developers make this use, so I'd like to understand what it means.

Comment: `function main(SimpleClass): void {}` is invalid, but `function main(SimpleClass $something): void` is a parameter with a type hint. If you pass it anything other than an instance of `SomeClass` it will cause an error. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php

Comment: @Sammitch Under what circumstances is it appropriate to use the instance of a class as a parameter?

Comment: Type hints are a good idea pretty much all the time, and with PHP 8 introducing composite types there's no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking of something like this...

```
class printable
{
    public function runHello(simpleClass $obj): void
    {
        $obj.sayHello();
    }
}
```

where the class 'printable' has a member function 'runHello' that takes a 'simpleClass' object as a parameter.

Your code (written above) has an error because you are passing a class without telling the compiler what you will be calling that class object inside main: you need a $variable after the text "main(SimpleClass" before the ")"